# How to efficiently filter a large python list?

Tags: python, arrays, filter, large-data

I have a relatively large array called `allListings` and want to filter out all rows where `allListings[:][14] == listingID`.

This is the code I am using:
`tempRows = list(filter(lambda x: x[14] == listingID, allListings))`

The filtering is repeated in a for loop for all different `listingID`

Profiling shows, that this line consumes 95% of the runtime in the loop.
Is there any other way to filter large arrays more efficiently?

Comment: Perhaps converted the list of lists to a dataframe then filtering that may be faster?

Comment: It would almost certainly be faster to use a list comprehension with a filtering `if` guard at the end. Your current way has the additional overhead of creating a generator and using `lambda`s.

Comment: You might get better performance by sorting once by `listingID` then using `itertools.groupby` to pull off the groups with the same ID. Alternatively you can make a dictionary with `listingID` keys and values as list of rows. Do this once, then all remaining access will be constance time.

Comment: Perhaps `tempRows = [row for row in allListings if row[14] == listingID]`. You could put that into a function (if its not there already) to speed variable access. This avoids the per-cell lambda call.

Comment: If this was already in a pandas DataFrame, it would be `tempRows = allListings[allListings[14]] == listingID` which looks similar but is faster, especially if these are native data types. Whether this is good depends on how easily your code converts to pandas.

Comment: Where is the array (or rather `list` it seems) coming from? The most efficient ways to solve this would be to use more efficient data structures like a `numpy` array or a `pandas` dataframe, but then it would also make sense to load the data into those directly, instead of converting from a list first.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: thanks for the quick reply. List comprehension is indeed 35% faster.

Comment: numpy array should be most efficient

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - But with a warning - it would only work if all columns were the same data type.

Comment: How about `tempRows = list(filter(lambda x: x[14] in list_of_listingIDs, allListings))` to skip your `for` loop

Comment: Originally I was using a NumPy array (not all columns are the same data type). My issue with the NumPy array was that it uses 10x as much memory (~11 Gb vs ~1.3 Gb) compared to the native list containing the same data. Surprisingly, the rows have similar memory usage (0.5kb vs 1kb) which leads me to believe that the NumPy data structure has a huge overhead.

Comment: @Francis111333 - that's going to depend on the data type. You may have been using fixed length `String_` and wasting a lot of space. Using pandas may help as it handles multiple data types. Also, you have to be mindful about keeping multiple copies of the array laying around.

Comment: I tested a 1,000,000 x 15 list of lists using `pypy` and it ran in about 25% of the time. Sometimes you can run your entire project via pypy3 (which compiles python) and get a great speed up. Other times its a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you may want to sort and group by this column if you are performing multiple operations on it based on the value of that column.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3, 5],
...      [4, 6, 2, 8],
...      [1, 5, 7, 9],
...      [3, 5, 8, 2]]
>>> b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 7, 9], [3, 5, 8, 2], [4, 6, 2, 8]]
>>> c = groupby(b, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> c
<itertools.groupby object at 0x106b763e0>
>>> d = {k: list(v) for k, v in c}
>>> d
{1: [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 7, 9]], 3: [[3, 5, 8, 2]], 4: [[4, 6, 2, 8]]}
```

Now, if you need all lists where the first element is `1`, you simply need:

```
>>> d[1]
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Or if you wanted everything *but* 1 in that first position.

```
>>> [x for k, v in d.items() 
...    if k != 1 
...    for x in v] 
[[3, 5, 8, 2], [4, 6, 2, 8]]
```

This is obviously a simpler example, but should be easily applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I am amazed at the efficiency of this solution. In my case, it takes 2.4s to do the preprocessing (sort, group, create dictionary), but after that accessing the filtered rows is just a normal read operation. Kudos to you!

Comment: good catch that the OP wants repeated `get`!

Answer (score 0):

I got about a 33% improvement by moving the filter to a [cython](https://cython.org) file and compiling. The primary speedup I think is in eliminating the reload of `listingID` for each compare. Just a guess on that.

test.pyx

```
def all_listings_filter(list data, int listingID):
    return [row for row in data if row[14] == listingID]
```

command line

```
cython3 test.pyx
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python3.10 -o test.so test.c
```